# About -(NSDictionary)dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: and

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary, foundation

I got a really interesting question.

Inside one of my classes I declared a very simple instance method -(NSDictionary)dictionary;
that is implemented in this way:

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              self.userID, @"id",
                              self.userName, @"name",
                              self.userSurname, @"sName",
                              self.userNickname, @"nName",
                              self.userPassword, @"pwd",
                              [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[self.userBirthday timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000], @"birthday",
                              self.userSex, @"sex",
                              self.userEmail, @"email",
                              self.userLanguage, @"locale",
                              [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:self.userCoin], @"coin",
                              self.userRate, @"rate",
                              [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.userCoordinate.latitude], @"lat",
                              [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.userCoordinate.longitude], @"lon",
                              self.userPlaces, @"userPlaces",
                              nil];
    }
```

with this method declared there are no @"userPlaces" key inside my return dictionary (self.userPlace is obviously valorized and full of objects).

So I changed a little bit my method like this:

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictionary {      
    NSMutableDictionary *toReturn = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [toReturn setValue:self.userID forKey:@"id"];
    [toReturn setValue:self.userName forKey:@"name"];
    [toReturn setValue:self.userSurname forKey:@"sName"];
    [toReturn setValue:self.userNickname forKey:@"nName"];
    [toReturn setValue:self.userPassword forKey:@"pwd"];
    [toReturn setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[self.userBirthday timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000] forKey:@"birthday"];
    [toReturn setValue:self.userSex forKey:@"sex"];
    [toReturn setValue:self.userEmail forKey:@"email"];
    [toReturn setValue:self.userLanguage forKey:@"locale"];
    [toReturn setValue:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:self.userCoin] forKey:@"coin"];
    [toReturn setValue:self.userRate forKey:@"rate"];
    [toReturn setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.userCoordinate.latitude] forKey:@"lat"];
    [toReturn setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.userCoordinate.longitude] forKey:@"lon"];
    [toReturn setValue:self.userPlaces forKey:@"userPlaces"];

    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:toReturn];
}
```

All the key are now present inside the output dictionary!!!

This problem drove me crazy to understand but my question is ...
There is any reason couse the second method works better then the first one??

I didn't find a reason for it.

Comment: Please note that the canonical method to add objects to a dictionary is `-setObject:forKey:`. You’re using `-setValue:forKey:`, which is a KVC method and has a peculiar behaviour as described in my comment to fluchtpunkt’s answer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:` stops to add objects when it finds a `nil` value.

So most likely one of the objects you try to add in the first code is nil.

Comment: If that’s the case (and it probably is), the OP would have caught it by using `-[NSMutableDictionary setObject:forKey:]` instead of `-[NSMutableDictionary setValue:forKey:]`. The former is the canonical method in `NSMutableDictionary` to add objects to the dictionary and it raises an exception when trying to add a `nil` object; the latter is a KVC method that, when sent to an `NSMutableDictionary` with a `nil` value, will attempt to remove the corresponding key and won’t throw an exception.

Comment: I totally forgot that `setValue:forKey:` allows nil and `setObject:forKey:` doesn't.

Answer (score 7):

The something similar to the code below solved my problem with the same exception:

```
(NSMutableDictionary *)dictionary {
return [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          self.userID, @"id",
                          self.userName, @"name",
                          self.userSurname, @"sName",
                          self.userNickname, @"nName",
                          self.userPassword, @"pwd",
                          [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[self.userBirthday timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000], @"birthday",
                          self.userSex, @"sex",
                          self.userEmail, @"email",
                          self.userLanguage, @"locale",
                          [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:self.userCoin], @"coin",
                          self.userRate, @"rate",
                          [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.userCoordinate.latitude], @"lat",
                          [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.userCoordinate.longitude], @"lon",
                          self.userPlaces, @"userPlaces",
                          nil];
}
```

Comment: I was looking for something else, but this idea is good. So voting up.